# Operator overloading - why static resolve?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

What are the reasons for resolving overloaded operators statically? It seems a strange choice to me - the only advantage I can think of is a small performance gain (but then the JIT may avoid that sometimes as well) at the cost of some rather unintuitive behavior - i.e. I basically have to forward the operator to a virtual function to get the wanted behavior.

Was this just taken over from C++ or are there some other good reasons for this?

Comment: "Design decision" .. now, where is Eric? ;-) Another somewhat related question is "why aren't methods virtual by default"?

Comment: He's here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/05/14/why-are-overloaded-operators-always-static-in-c.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Eric Lipperts article [Why are overloaded operators always static in C#?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/05/14/why-are-overloaded-operators-always-static-in-c.aspx)

> Rather, the question we should be asking ourselves when faced with a potential language feature is "does the compelling benefit of the feature justify all the costs?" And costs are considerably more than just the mundane dollar costs of designing, developing, testing, documenting and maintaining a feature. There are more subtle costs, like, will this feature make it more difficult to change the type inferencing algorithm in the future? Does this lead us into a world where we will be unable to make changes without introducing backwards compatibility breaks? And so on.
>
> **In this specific case, the compelling benefit is small. If you want to have a virtual dispatched overloaded operator in C# you can build one out of static parts very easily.** [...]

It is be possible to support instance based operators but the C# language designer did not see the big gain compared to the efforts needed to make it work correctly.

Comment: I swear Eric copies and pastes that first paragraph in all his articles that relate to C# design :-)

Comment: Nice link by an authority on the topic great and yes he's right about some possible pitfalls there (and then the solution is simple enough anyhow - just not as elegant as I'd like it).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case of when overloading the operator for a reference type. It could be `null` on either side of the operator.

If operators were instance methods, they wouldn't work.

Comment: But Scala allows "operator overloading" on reference types: `x * y` is no different than `x.multiply(y)` in Scala after the parsing.

Comment: Just coming up with a counter-argument :) Also, I have been bit with Nullable types here, dunno where they fit in all this: `(int)?10 > (int?)null` ... makes sense in the end, but still has caused be some grief :(

Comment: Yep you'd obviously have to specify at least how the arguments are evaluated (although `x op y` being `x.op(y)` seems like the logical choice). I can see the argument about the asymmetry there though.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that come off the top of my head, either one of which would IMHO suffice to break the deal by itself:

1. **Which operators?** Binary operators have two operands, and dynamic dispatch based on the types of *two* arguments is not available! "Classic" `virtual` methods are dispatched based on just the runtime type of `this`.
2. What would be the use case that justifies the additional complexity?