# Why polymorphism doesn't work on operators via object types?

Tags: c#, polymorphism

The code demo is outlined here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mCm8Hx

If I have a class that overrides `Equals` and operators `==` and `!=`, I can compare them via variables typed as that class.

But if I cast them to `object` (or use variables typed as object that are assigned to instances of that class), the operator doesn't seem to be used anymore.

E.g. this would work:

```
var a1 = new MyClass(5);
var a2 = new MyClass(5);
Console.WriteLine(a1 == a2); // prints "true" because I've implemented == operator
```

This also works (`MySubClass : MyClass`):

```
var b1 = new MySubClass(10);
var b2 = new MySubClass(10);
Console.WriteLine(b1 == b2); // prints "true" because I've implemented == operator in inherited class MyClass
```

But this doesn't:

```
object o1 = a1;
object o2 = a2;
Console.WriteLine(o1 == o2); //prints "false", doesn't use my operator implementation
```

Since all classes inherit implicitly from `Object`, I'd expect it to work the same way as it works with `MySubClass`. Why this isn't the case with `object` typed vars?

Comment: And be glad it doesn't. You won't know if your `x == null` check would break due to a subclass (Edit: oh, and generics). *Which is also one of the reasons some people argue for `x is null` or `ReferenceEquals(x, null)`.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operator overloading - why static resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526493/operator-overloading-why-static-resolve)

Comment: Operators are static is the quick and simple answer

Comment: Which operator to use is resolved at compile time, based on the types involved, not the actual runtime types involved but the type of the expressions involved. That's why. If you need runtime support, use `.Equals` instead, which is virtual and can thus be overridden by your own types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all let's look at the Object class itself:

[image]

As you can see the Equals method has `virtual` key on it, meaning that in any class that inherits from object, if you `override` that method, then even if your variable `object o2 = a2;` is typeof object pointing to new instance of `A` class -> this method will be invoked by the runtime:

`public override bool Equals(object other)`

On the other hand the `operator ==` is not `virtual`, it cannot be overriden, so when referring to `object` variable it will always resolve to [System.Object.ReferenceEquals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Object_ReferenceEquals_System_Object_System_Object_)